# Measure distance between component and top of viewport in React Native and update with scrolling / layout changes?

Tags: react-native

I need to measure the distance between a component and the top of the screen, and then pass this value down to a child.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    containerHeight: 0
  };

  handleLayoutChange() {
    this.conainerView.measure(
      (fx, fy, containerWidth, containerHeight, px, yOffsetToPage) => {
        this.setState({ containerHeight });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        onLayout={event => {
          this.handleLayoutChange(event);
        }}
        ref={view => {
          this.conainerView = view;
        }}
      >
        <Child containerHeight={this.state.containerHeight} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The code above works on page load but doesn't update as you scroll (a parent component has a ScrollView) or if the orientation changes. What is the "normal" solution to this? Im quite new to React Native but it feels like I'm writing a lot of code for quite a simple thing so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ScrollView />` component have a props called [onScroll](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll) with params included offset values follow this form `nativeEvent: { contentInset: { bottom, left, right, top }, contentOffset: { x, y }, contentSize: { height, width }, layoutMeasurement: { height, width }, zoomScale } }`

I think you can use it to listen scroll events and calculating the new measurement value.

Because your example codes not completed. So i can not write completed solution code for you

Comment: I could listen to scroll events from the ScrollView parent component, but I would also need to listen to orientation change and window resize (I'm also making a web app with React Native Web). I think I can get it working but it's going to be a lot of code and and indirection, which makes me wonder if I'm taking the wrong approach.